# InnoDB: what is a clustered index and what are use cases?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, innodb

I need a explaining of clustered index. With Google I found only SQL Server info, not MySQL/InnoDB.

- What is a clustered index?
- What are best practices for using the clustered index?
- What are MySQL specific limitations?

Comment: The definition of a clustered index is pretty similar across databases.  So, if you don't know anything about what they are, the SQL Server description is probably a good enough introduction.

Comment: And There is explanations in Mysql documentation.

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL...  (Caveat:  The answers for other vendors is slightly different.)

There are two main "engines" in MySQL, MyISAM and InnoDB.

For InnoDB, the `PRIMARY KEY` ("PK") has these characteristics.  (MyISAM is different.)

- There can be only one PK.
- The PK is UNIQUE and it is an INDEX.
- The PK is "clustered" with the data.
- The PK is organized in a [B+Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree).

Within that BTree, the entire records are stored, but ordered in PK order.  A BTree is a set of "blocks", each of which has some number of rows "clustered" together in PK-order.

Since loading a block takes I/O (unless cached), and I/O takes time, it is handy that several rows are fetched at the same time.  This 'clustering' principle provides speed.

Hence, one feature:  Reading consecutively through the PK is very efficient.  Example:  `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id BETWEEN 10 and 19;`

Each "Secondary" key is in a separate BTrees.  This makes a "range" scan within it efficient -- partially.  Example:

```
PRIMARY KEY(id)
INDEX(other)
SELECT * FROM table WHERE other >= 123
```

That will drill into the BTree for `other` to find 123, then scan forward (arguably a form of clustering, but not really a "clustered index") efficiently to find the values of `other` that are desired.  For each of them it will reach into the clustered PK to find the `*` columns of the table.  (Note:  The PK is stored in the secondary key's BTree; this is how to get from the secondary key all the way back to the data.)

**Best practices:**  Almost always use InnoDB; always have a `PRIMARY KEY`.

**MySQL-specific limitations:**  There are no other "clustered indexes".

*Addenda*

The TokuDB Engine (Included with MariaDB 10; free plugin for other versions of MySQL) is another "Engine".  It has [more clustering options](http://www.tokutek.com/2009/05/introducing_multiple_clustering_indexes/).

Comment: Percona TokuDB allows for additional clustering indexes though. Since TokuDB is a drop-in replacement and it's free (if I'm not mistaken), it would be good to add that info to this answer. Nevertheless, +1, great answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder.  (However, today `InnoDB` is the primary engine in use.)